# How to make a query on a django model passed as a function parameter

Tags: django, function, django-models, django-orm

Having my models defined

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    some_attribute_1 = models.IntegerField

class Model2(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    some_attribute_2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I want to build a function :

```
def my_function(model, desc):
    return model.objects.filter(description = desc)
```

And use it as

```
str1 = my_function(Model1, "some description")
str2 = my_function(Model2, "some description")
```

Comment: Ok, what's stopping you? That code would work exactly as described.

Comment: did you implemented it? and faced any errors? then let us know about the problem